# Possible values of characteristic functions (Fourier transforms)

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

Can a characteristic function $\varphi_{X}(u)$ from probability theory (the Fourier transform of a probability measure) ever equal zero for either any value of $x$ or any value of $u$?

This has been a huge matter of debate on my probability class, and yesterday, our professor said he believed that it could be the case, but I am not sure.

Comment: What GotLost said above. It can certainly be zero for _some_ value of $u$, eg let $X$ be uniform in $[-1,1]$, then $\varphi_{X}(u)$ is a $sinc$  function

Comment: CF correspond basically to "positive definite" functions (with the additional restrictiction $\varphi_X(0)=1$ ) See eg http://www.ime.usp.br/~spjm/articlepdf/464.pdf

Comment: Yes, GotLost, that is what I meant.

Comment: I am curious: which specific characteristic functions did you actually compute, either in class or by yourself?

Comment: Ones for various probability distributions.